# Calling function gives an error

Tags: python, function

I have define the "rev" function and gives the parameter called "text". Returned the value, however when I am calling rev function it gives me the Syntax error.

I need help. Code is below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6v7v.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation so we know what the actual error is. And what's the exact error message?

Comment: This is the nature of stackoverflow. We accept **quality** answers that we can **reliably** answer. We arent bullying here, we are trying to teach you how the site works, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Site Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as prompted when you made this account.

Comment: Others are just trying to point out the obvious mistakes.Chill. Which environment you are using?

Comment: @mad_ I am using Idle and I understood the error.. :-)

Comment: Please include the code in the question as text an image is useless for future users (they can't search for it). I know SO can be hard but we really are trying to create good Q/A for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your code as posted here, delete the indent before def. Otherwise it works for me just fine. If that is not your issue please post the error you are getting.

Comment: Indentation is never a problem, yes I made a mistake its a human error. As I mentioned code is not working, I use proper indentation, go through the attached screenshot

Comment: In the python terminal prompt, you have to hit enter again between when you define the function and when you call it. Python thinks `rev("just")` is part of the function definition otherwise.

Comment: Thanks brother, It worked. I am new to python but will learn with the help of you guys. Thanks again